# WPF User Control Apply Style

Tags: wpf

I created a custom TimePicker control. It has a label and some combo boxes on it. It is inside a UserControl library.

Now I added a reference to that project in my Desktop project and added the TimePicker to a window.

Finally, I have some styles defined in a 3rd project. I would like to create a style in the Styles project for the TimePicker on my window.

How do I set that TimePicker's style in the Desktop project?

Answer (score 0):

1. Load Resource Dictionary from your style project.
2. Set button style defined in your Resource Dictionary.

Comment: That's exactly what I DON'T want to do... because then the UC library will always need THAT resource dict... The UC library can be used in any project, so it can't know about styles. The style needs to be applied AFTER the control is used.